# How to get TP-Link WN722N working with Fedora 17 Remix?

Tags: wireless

I copied the `htc_9271.fw` file into `/lib/firmware` as per [RPi VerifiedPeripherals - eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Working_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters).

The output of `lsusb` shows that the device is connected. However, `iwconfig` does not show any interface with wireless capabilities.

What else do i have to do?

Comment: Terry, have you looked at your `dmesg` for messages from the [`ath9k_htc` driver](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k_htc)? Is the driver actually installed? More details about this device: http://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N

Comment: @Lekensteyn I just found the time to play with the pi again. Indeed the `ath9k_htc` driver is not installed. I was confused between the `ath9k` and the `ath9k_htc` drivers. Is there a way to install it on the Fedora Remix 17?

Comment: I have no experience with that distro, isn't it already available in the `/lib/modules` directory? If not, you can try to build an OOT kernel module, recompile the kernel (after enabling the module) or ask the Fedora Remix developers to do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did figure out how to do this eventually. I already posted this on my [blog](http://www.infosecstudent.com/2013/05/how-to-compile-the-ath9k_htc-driver-for-the-raspberry-pi-fedora-17-remix/) but I figured I'll answer this here to close out my question.

Before performing any sort of compilation, you need to have the necessary tools.

```
yum install make gcc
```

Grab the kernel source from github and unpack it.

```
sudo bash
cd /usr/src
wget  https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tarball/rpi-3.2.27
mv rpi-3.2.27
tar xzf rpi-3.2.27
```

Next, grab the configurations from the running kernel and prepare the source tree.

```
cd raspberrypi-linux-*
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
make oldconfig
make modules_prepare
```

Finally, prepare the symlinks in /lib/modules/[kernelversion]/

```
KSRC=`pwd`
pushd /lib/modules/`uname -r`
ln -s ${KSRC} source
ln -s ${KSRC} build
popd

pushd /usr/src
ln -s ${KSRC} linux-`uname -r`
ln -s ${KSRC} linux
popd
```

For specific wireless adapters, you might require a firmware file. The wireless card I am working with, TL-WN722N requires the htc_9271.fw file.

```
cd /lib/firmware
wget http://linuxwireless.org/download/htc_fw/1.3/htc_9271.fw
```

Grab the driver source and unpack it.

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.8/compat-drivers-3.8-1-u.tar.bz2
tar xvf compat-drivers-3.8-1-u.tar.bz2
```

Next, add the Module.symvers file into the source directory.

```
cd compat-drivers-3.8-1-u
wget https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/raw/master/extra/Module.symvers
```

Next, compile and install the driver.

```
./scripts/driver-select ath9k_htc
make
make install
```

Finally, unload the existing modules to prevent any conflicts.

```
make unload
```

Sources:

[compat-drivers documentation](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation/compat-drivers)

[Raspberry Pi forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=179845#p179845)

Comment: Great work, but... The command `mv rpi-3.2.27` seems to be wrong... no destination is specified. What should it be? Can it not be omitted?